# set picklist default value

Tags: picklist, dependent-picklist, field-dependencies

For the **Deployment Scenario** picklist - the default option is 'not completed'

I have created field dependencies, to ensure that Alibaba, AWS, Azure, Google, IBM Cloud, Oracle Cloud are only displayed as options on the **Cloud Platform** picklist, when Hybrid is selected.

When 'Hybrid' is selected, the picklist value on **Cloud Platform** should default to 'Azure'. Is it possible to set a default like this?
[image]

**Edit**:
Additional variation:
When 'Partner Hosted (MSP)' is selected, the picklist value on **Cloud Platform** should default to 'IBM Cloud'.
[image]

Comment: Edit this picklist field and set default value field.

Comment: Please see Edit for additional variation @itzmukeshy7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not currently possible. The only option you currently have is to set an *initial* default value for the dependent picklist on creation. This will only work assuming you also set a default on the controlling picklist that maps to that value.

What I gather you're asking for is the ability to have it dynamically change dependent picklists in the edit/create page based on changes to the controlling picklist the user actively makes. There's no out of the box option for that.

It'd have to be done in a custom LWC/Aura that overrides the `Create`/`Edit` button and you'd have to replicate the screen with [record-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation)/[record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) with `onchange` event. That would allow you to implement the logic to change the value of the dependent picklist based on the change of the value in the controlling picklist the user makes in real-time on the screen.